# drupal homepage working - all other pages give a 404

Tags: drupal, web-hosting

I am new to drupal, I am able to access website homepage fine but i unable to open other pages. its showing like 404 page error. please help me on these issue.

Website Name: http://moserfarmshomes.com

Comment: can you list the installed module ?

Comment: I installed few number of modules, even i unable to see login screen. http://moserfarmshomes.com/user/

Comment: may you have a access content module which got a bad configuration :s

Answer (score 2):

It might be a wrong configuration in you clean-url setup? Look in .htaccess and ?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `$base_url` in `settings.php` to **http://moserfarmshomes.com**

Comment: And, what version of Drupal are we talking about?

Comment: thank you, i changed as you suggested, but i am getting same 404 page error.

Comment: I think you need to install. You probably took a wrong step somewhere. I am willing to help through the chat facility if you are interested in some guidance

Comment: thank you very much. i resloved the issue. issue is .httaccess files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a fresh install of Drupal.

Try following the steps of this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vPnlK1yiLw

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me it turned out I was missing the .htaccess in my install directory.

So check you copied that as well since it is a hidden file it's easy to forget this.